# What should we do about the "mistakes in this Specsavers ad" question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

["What are all the mistakes in this Specsavers ad?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/89229/46980) has proven to be a very popular question - as I type this, it has almost 14,000 views and counting. However, because of that, it seems to be attracting a lot of low-quality answers.

Currently, of the five answers on the question, four are from 1-rep users, and list only two or three mistakes compared to the accepted answer's 17. [This one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92481/46980) and [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/89468/46980) are both attempts to reply to the accepted answer, saying "you forgot these ones", and [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/93293/46980) almost entirely consists of mistakes that are *already* in the accepted answer. I don't have enough rep to see whether there are any deleted answers, but I strongly suspect there are.

I don't think this should be allowed to continue. This question needs sorting out. I suggest taking the following steps:

1. Delete the 1-rep answers and edit them into the accepted answer
2. Turn the accepted answer into a Community answer, so anyone who spots additional mistakes can just edit them in (this is the usual procedure on SciFi.SE regarding "what are all the X in Y?" questions)
3. Protect the question to make sure there are no further 1-rep drive-by answerers

Is this an acceptable course of action, or going too far? If not this, then what *should* we do about this question?

Comment: It is protected now. So, that would stop 1 rep answers with repeating mistakes. I have no problem converting the answer to a CW if community thinks it right. In fact, I have approved edit suggestions to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You laid out the...pretty much best course for things like this in your question. So yes, that's about what should, and ultimately will, be done with the question.

We occasionally get such "what are all the things" list questions and they often come with quite a few problems, as demonstrated by this exemplar too. Sometimes they get closed for various reasons, sometimes they make it into reasonable and successful questions, like this one. But really the only way to get these things working is often through a giant Community Wiki answer, as you explained.

Since this one has a quite extensive answer, I'd rather count it to the successful ones, but yes, we definitely have to do something to contain the damage.

Comment: I...have to admit, though, that right now I personally don't really feel like scanning the existing answers for duplicates in the big list at the moment. So if anyone feels like cleaning this up, go for it and feel free to flag the answers when done.

Comment: i added a comment to the one to three offs that we prefer canonical answers

Comment: Seems noone involved in that question and aware of the ad felt the need to clean up those answers yet. I guess I *do* have to delve into this thing at some point.