# Would a question about identifying all universes in the Arrowverse be allowed?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

If I would ask a question to identify all universes existing in the Arrowverse, would this be closed as an ID Question, or would it be able to exist as a community wiki answer?

The fact that this is a big event on television, I predict several questions will appear about the same thing, also several questions about this already have been asked.

Comment: That's not really an ID question at all. Though, it might still be an inappropriate question nevertheless. There's not just these two categories of questions and not everything that has the word "identify" in its question's concept is an "identification question" in the sense of this site. So this dichotomy is a bit flawed.

Comment: This one is a finite list question which can be answered and should be allowed as per my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

I personally don't see any applicable close reasons:

- It's not an ID question because you're asking to identify an *in-universe* aspect of the show(s), not a real-world aspect like an actor or song.
- It's not a list question because there is a finite set of answers. Making it Community Wiki would probably be a good idea, though, to prevent [issues we've had before](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4335/46980) with similar questions. (To be extra safe, I'd make it clear in the question that you're looking for universes that are **known** to exist in the Arrowverse, as the ones that *aren't* known are potentially infinite in number. But maybe that's just me being pedantic.)
- It's not a trivia question because it's relevant to the upcoming *Crisis on Infinite Earths* crossover event.

Unfortunately, though, [it seems someone else has beaten you to the punch](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/105534/46980). Sorry!

Comment: Your first point is *still* a bit misleading. Identifying "real-world aspects" isn't what ID questions are about either. A question asking for a song is *not* an ID question.

Comment: Also his question seems to be different from the one asked already, as he is asking for all universe not the one appeared in supergirl.  Also community wiki is only useful if you need multiple people to answer it but for arrowverse one person can answer it to as I tried.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I thought soundtrack ID questions were off-topic here?

Comment: @F1Krazy They *might* be, if they don't relate to the film. But if they're anything, it's not ID. "ID question" and "off-topic question" are *not* synonyms.